# my cookie isn't set forever

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies

I use the jQuery.min.js of https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie
and my cookie code:

```
$(function() {

    //hide all divs just for the purpose of this example, 
    //you should have the divs hidden with your css

    //check if the cookie is already setted
    if ($.cookie("_usci") === undefined){
            $.cookie("_usci",1);
    } else { //else..well   

            var numValue = parseInt($.cookie("_usci"));
            numValue = numValue + 1;
            else{ //no issues, assign the incremented value
                $.cookie("_usci",numValue.toString());
            }

    }


    //just to add a class number to it
    //$('.current-number').addClass($.cookie("currentDiv"));
    //to add 'n + 1/2/3/4/5/6/7/8/9/10 etc.'
    $('.current-number').addClass("n"+$.cookie("_usci"));
    $('.current-number-large').addClass("n"+$.cookie("_usci"));
});
```

Because of some reason when I quit my browser and open it again the cookie is not set anymore and will reset, how can I solve this?

Comment: Assuming this is what you're using for `$.cookie()`: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie#readme   you need to specify an expiry value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie#expires):

```
$.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value', { expires: 7 });
```

`expire` define lifetime of the cookie. Value can be a Number which will be interpreted as days from time of creation or a Date object. If omitted, the cookie becomes a session cookie.

So for your case:

```
$.cookie('_usci', numValue.toString(), { expires: 5 * 365 });
```

This will make your cookie expire in five years from now.

Comment: I have this:$.cookie('_usci', 'numValue', { expires: 4 }); but this will give a Nan error

Comment: Glad I helped. Please accept the answer if it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

You must add the expire days when create the cookie:

```
$.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value', { expires: 7 }); // this cookie expires in 7 days
```

From the documentation:

`Define lifetime of the cookie. Value can be a Number which will be interpreted as days from time of creation or a Date object. If omitted, the cookie becomes a session cookie.`

Being a session cookie it will be automatically deleted when the browser is closed.

In your code:

```
//check if the cookie is already setted
if ($.cookie("_usci") === undefined){
    $.cookie("_usci", 1, { expires: 7 });
} else {
    var numValue = parseInt($.cookie("_usci"));
    $.cookie("_usci", numValue++, { expires: 7 });
}
```

Comment: In my case the cookie is _usci but what is the value I have to place?

Comment: I have this:$.cookie('_usci', 'numValue', { expires: 4 }); but this will give a Nan error

Comment: I've edited my answer.. please try the example above

Comment: Thanks works fine too, but I prefer the answer above this answer